# Broke My Asset Pipeline

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline, assets

I reviewed the many posts on this topic but can't seem to find the combination to fix my problem.  Sorry if this is a repeat.

Problem is I'm not sure the sequence of steps I took to get to this point.

I had a perfectly functioning Rails app in both development and production on Heroku.  However, on Heroku deploy, I was getting an error during the asset precompilation.  So, I changed settings so Heroku would assume 'rake asset:precompile' had been run locally before deploy.  Got rid of the deploy error, no problem.  Somewhat annoying that I had to now precompile locally and include the files in my Git repository, but I liked the no-error deploy.

Anyway, now in development, changes to CSS weren't being reflected on-the-fly.  I'd have to run 'rake assets:precomplile'.  That's no good.  Found a post that deleting public/assets would fix that, which it did.

Now Javascript/Coffeescript changes don't get reflected on-the-fly.

Sorry for the longwinded description.

Ideally, I'd get to a world where changes are reflected on-the-fly in development, I don't need to run 'rake assets:precomplile' before Heroku deploy, and I don't get an error during precompile on Heroku.

Less ideally, I'd just get back to my initial behavior (where Heroku complained on deploy, but everything still worked fine).

Comment: Do you know exactly what are the settings to change to make heroku assume `rake assets:precompile` has been run locally ? And btw did you try what is suggested here ? https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails3x-asset-pipeline-cedar basically, use `config.initialize_on_precompile = false`

Comment: Yes.  I have config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false.

Comment: And what about the settings you changed ?

Comment: I believe I added `config.assets.compile = true` to my production.rb to handle cases where I forgot to precompile before Heroku deploy (assuming that was ok while my app is in beta and not widely deployed).

Comment: A quick more generic question first... If I'm configured this way, am I going to have to delete public/assets after I deploy each time I `rake assets:precompile`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to precompile the assets on the fly use (for example `config/production.erb`)

```
config.assets.compile = true
config.assets.precompile << '*.js'
```

Then look in `config/application.rb` there you can choose if you want to precompile before deploying to production

```
if defined?(Bundler)
  # If you precompile assets before deploying to production, use this line
  Bundler.require(*Rails.groups(:assets => %w(development test)))
  # If you want your assets lazily compiled in production, use this line
  # Bundler.require(:default, :assets, Rails.env)
end
```